# How in AngularJS ng-repeat get hold of item key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Docs: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set
>   to the item index or key.

It seems like I'm getting the **index** not the **key**.

---

Controller:

```
$scope.items = {
  "key1" : "val1",
  "key2" : "val2"
};
```

View:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ $index }} {{item}}</div>
```

Result:

```
0 val1
1 val2
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0g9EL6kqYcm4jNpdDZ9L?p=preview

I'd like to display **key**, which in this case should be `key1` and `key2`. Is there a special syntax for that?

Comment: It's a shame that you've found the documentation, but can't even read it entirely…

Comment: Sorry internet, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{ $index }} {{key}} {{value}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="(key, val) in items">{{ key }} {{ val }}</div>
```

Here's the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/nWqK8rFVaKzzEpbAuqdx?p=preview

And here's the corresponding point from the docs:

> (key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user
>   defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the
>   collection to enumerate.
>
> For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat